# Kotlin annotation changing of target

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I have a annotation AggregateId that could be set on method params and properties and that I will use to retrieve some id :

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class AggregateId
```

I wrote that test case :

```
data class Example(
    @AggregateId
    val id: UUID
)

class AggregateIdTests {

    private val exUuid = UUID.fromString("bae30706-f949-4eb5-b091-d51a13ddc832")

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val ex = Example(id = exUuid)
        val id = resolve(ex)

        Assertions.assertThat(id).isEqualTo(exUuid)
    }

    private fun resolve(target: Any): UUID? {
        val prop = target::class.declaredMemberProperties.find {
            it.findAnnotation<AggregateId>() != null
        }

        return prop?.getter?.call(target) as UUID?
    }
}
```

That actually works.
But if I add this class in the code :

```
class TestClass {
    fun aMethod(@AggregateId param: UUID) {

    }
}
```

Suddently the AggregateId changes of target for the other class. Even though I didn't change the rest of the code. What is the explaination of this ?
(using kotlin 1.5)